# What is the possible application of eigenvalues?

Tags: discrete-signals, matrix, cosine, eigendecomposition

I am a PhD in mathematics. Recently, we made an [attempt](https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.08222) to compute the eigenvalues of ***non-normalized*** discrete sine and cosine transforms. Surprisingly, the issue regarding three particular types, DCT-I, DCT-V, and DST-VIII, is rather complicated. Anyway, my question pertains to finding possible applications.

I mean, what could be the next step in the application when you have the eigenvalues and eigenbasis (an orthogonal basis consisting of eigenvectors) of discrete trigonometric transforms? Any references to previous studies?